# pagination on ui-bootstrap-tpls 1.0.0 or next do not display

Tags: angularjs, pagination, angular-ui-bootstrap

I use "pagination" directive of ui-bootstrap-tpls

```
<pagination total-items="totalItems" ng-model="currentPage" ng-change="pageChanged()"></pagination>
```

[plnkr Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/zijYdoMdAVFg1GG2P3FH?p=preview) with 0.14.3 of ui-bootstrap-tpls is **OK**

[image]

[plnkr Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/nSflHQ7W8BoAn3yGR4jy?p=preview) with 1.0.0 of ui-bootstrap-tpls is **KO**

[image]

What modification should be made please?

Comment: can you be more clear about your problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in version **0.x.x** you use ([demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/zijYdoMdAVFg1GG2P3FH?p=preview)):

```
<pagination total-items="totalItems" ng-model="currentPage" ng-change="pageChanged()"></pagination>
```

in version **1.x.x** you need use ([demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/nUW35lVS031vN4IKSdvf?p=preview)):

```
<uib-pagination total-items="totalItems" ng-model="currentPage" ng-change="pageChanged()"></uib-pagination>
```

in version **2.x.x** you need use ([demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/mh7NWZekTqCVrPywcpFO?p=preview)):

```
<ul uib-pagination total-items="totalItems" ng-model="currentPage" ng-change="pageChanged()"></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

All bootstrap directives were renamed. (i.e. pagination -> uib-pagination) Look https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ - pagination example from there work with 1.0.0 of ui-bootstrap-tpls as well.

Comment: I change pagination by uib-pagination. I solve for version 1.0.0 but not for version 2.3.2. What modification should be made please? Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/IwhYGwPk08ImbOD1CcKE?p=preview

Comment: really go and open that latest example from link - it is in plunker... You can not just change js library versions - there is never backward compatability.